# proxmox lxc UID/GID mapping

Tags: lxc, proxmox

I have connected a host system directory to an lxc container, configured a read/write UID/GID mapping of the user in the connected directory.
After starting the container, the permissions on the directory are correct, but all permissions of this user in the container have changed to nobody:nogroup.

How to do UID/GID mapping correctly?

```
/etc/subuid
```

```
root:100000:65536
root:1001:1
```

```
/etc/subgid
```

```
root:100000:65536
root:1001:1
```

```
/etc/pve/lxc/100.conf
```

```
arch: amd64
cores: 4
cpulimit: 4
features: fuse=1,nesting=1
hostname: opensearch-01-v1.0.0
memory: 8192
mp0: /srv/nfs/opensearch-01/data,mp=/var/lib/opensearch
nameserver: 10.3.0.165 10.3.0.166
net0: name=eth0,bridge=vmbr1,gw=10.3.4.254,hwaddr=BA:65:74:12:69:34,ip=10.3.4.174/24,tag=40,type=veth
ostype: debian
rootfs: vms:100/vm-100-disk-0.raw,size=25G
searchdomain: mnc078.mcc250.dsrc.labics.ru
swap: 4096
unprivileged: 1
lxc.idmap: u 0 100000 1001
lxc.idmap: g 0 100000 1001
lxc.idmap: u 1001 1001 1
lxc.idmap: g 1001 1001 1
lxc.idmap: u 1002 101002 64534
lxc.idmap: g 1002 101002 64534
```

```
ls -l /etc/opensearch
```

```
-rw------- 1 nobody nogroup  1704 янв 12 17:17 esnode-key.pem
-rw------- 1 nobody nogroup  1529 янв 12 17:17 esnode.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup  3065 янв 12 17:37 jvm.options
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup  4096 окт 14  2022 jvm.options.d
-rw------- 1 nobody nogroup  1704 янв 12 17:17 kirk-key.pem
-rw------- 1 nobody nogroup  1655 янв 12 17:17 kirk.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup 14808 окт 14  2022 log4j2.properties
-rw-rw---- 1 nobody nogroup   196 янв 12 17:18 opensearch.keystore
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup  4096 янв 12 17:17 opensearch-notifications
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup  4096 янв 12 17:17 opensearch-notifications-core
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup  4096 янв 12 17:17 opensearch-observability
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup  4096 янв 12 17:17 opensearch-performance-analyzer
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup  4096 янв 12 17:17 opensearch-reports-scheduler
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup  4096 янв 12 17:17 opensearch-security
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup  6240 янв 12 17:34 opensearch.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup  6211 янв 12 17:28 opensearch.yml.sample
-rw------- 1 nobody nogroup  1716 янв 12 17:17 root-ca.pem
```